# See what file system mount is using with -t auto

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

How can I see what file system mount is using when I use the "-t auto" flag?

I am using a minimal build of Yocto Linux so I cannot simply use "file" to see what it is after the fact.

Comment: Do you have the usual `df` command?  The `-T` option includes a column for filesystem type.  If not, you'll want to extract it from `/proc/mounts`.

Comment: My version of BusyBox only gives Pkmh for df, no -T option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filesystem type is the third column in `/proc/mounts`; to extract that column, you can write:

```sh
awk '{print $3}' /proc/mounts
```

To make it more specific, you need to match the second column with your mountpoint:

```sh
awk "\$2 == \"$mountpoint\" {print \$3}" /proc/mounts
```

Answer (score 0):

`man mount`  gives a verbose description of *that* case:

> If no `-t` option is given, or if the ***auto*** type is specified, mount will
>   try to guess the desired type.  Mount  uses  the
>                 ***blkid***  library  for guessing the filesystem type; if that does not turn up anything that looks familiar, mount will try
>                 to read the file `/etc/filesystems`, or, if that does not exist, `/proc/filesystems`.  All of the filesystem types  listed
>                 there  will be tried, except for those that are labeled `"nodev"` (e.g., `devpts`, `proc` and `nfs`).  If `/etc/filesystems` ends
>                 in a line with a single `*`, mount will read `/proc/filesystems` afterwards.  While trying, all filesystem  types 
>   will  be
>                 mounted with the mount option silent.

Comment: My question was more directed at, once it finds a filesystem that works (i.e. it guesses correctly), is there a command to show which one it picked?